# Perl script to update contents of file with records

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing some details of a user. I have written a perl script to update the contents of this file ,only updating the user name.
Below is the format of content of the file -

```
//Details of John
User John is
  details1:(group = "abc")
  end detail1;
  detail2:(team = "pqr")
  end detail2;
  other_detail1:(someOtherDetail = John_123)
  end other_detail1;
end user John;
```

The format rules allows following - 
1)The Content can be in Upper case (eg. USER John ......END USER John;)
2)The last line can be written as - 
 2.1)end ; (number of spaces after end does not matter)
 2.2)end user John; 
 2.3)end John; 
 3)User name(John) can be written with escape characters like \John.In such case new file will also contain user name with escape sequence.
Now I want only "John" to change at lines - "User John is" & "end user John"(if john is present.In case 2.1 John is not present) & rest details remain same in updated file.

Following is my perl script -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
BEGIN {undef $/;}

my $match;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open (INFILE, "<", $filename)  or  die "Failed to read file $filename : $! \n";

$string =  <INFILE>;
close INFILE;

$match = "(?<=user )(.*?)$ARGV[2](.*?)(?<=end )(.*?)$ARGV[2]";
$string =~ s/$match/$1$ARGV[1]$2$3$ARGV[1]/gis;

open OUTFILE, ">$ARGV[0]" || die "Failed to create $ARGV[0]\n";
print OUTFILE ($string);
close OUTFILE;
```

The input to this script is in form - 
myscript filepath new_name old_name

This works for every rule explained above except 2.1 .Please suggest a way so that $match can work for rule 2.1.

Also I want to know if in any case end of detail(s) will affect "end user...;" since I am using end in $match.

Comment: How can that regex distinguish `end detailX`; from `end John;` ?

Comment: What is unique in a record ... `//Details of` perhaps? Having so many `end` words will make parsing the file as a whole picky. It'd be nice if you can separate records first.

Comment: Would [`^user\h+\KJohn\b|^end\h+(?:user\h+)?(?:John\b)?`](https://regex101.com/r/ZDbQPj/2) work for you?

Comment: @zdim That is what I felt. But since I have $ARGV[2] at the end in $match it copies everything till John(at the end). I know it may not be correct. Please suggest changes that can work in all cases.Thanks

Comment: I am looking at it, and my first comment meant to say that I don't think you can do that easily when the name is absent.  But my second comment conveys that more information would be needed -- is there something unique in a record? An empty line? Un-indented lines? That `//Detail...` line?

Comment: @ctwheels I thinsk I will not be able to write it in perl script as  - ^user\h+\K$ARGV[2]\b|^end\h+(?:user\h+)?(?:$ARGV[2]\b)? in positive lookahead

Comment: It's not part of your question, but this line is broken: `open OUTFILE, ">$ARGV[0]" || die "Failed to create $ARGV[0]\n";` - you need to use brackets, or `or` instead of `||`, because of precedence. Also - why not write two separate regex?

Comment: @BigA there aren't any positive lookaheads in my pattern. Just give it a try and let me know it if works for you.

Comment: What file format is this?

Comment: Without a name for end: (1) With `user NAME` start, you can't easily distinguish `end detail` and `end user` and `end;` for the record end.  You can, though, go line by line and when you see `user NAME` again then back up, since then you know that a record just finished. That's messy though. It will be much easier if _there is something unique in a record_.

Comment: @zdim The only uniqueness I can think of is that John which I have to update can only precede with \,<space> & can be followed by \,<space> or ; .If \ appears before and after John it should have <space> before and after \. Will setting regex as (\s[\\]*)$ARGV[2]([\\;]*\s) work?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It looks like someone wanted a database, but decided to invent their own file format instead. If you have a particular reason for not storing this data in a database, then please consider using an industry-standard file format like JSON, YAML or XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a mistake here, in that you're looking for a single magic regex.

Instead, you should be breaking your problem down because it's both clearer and easier to write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my ( $input_filename, $newname, $oldname ) = @ARGV;
open ( my $input, '<', $input_filename ) or die $!;


while ( <$input> ) { 

   #match start of user stanza
   if ( /^User $oldname is/i ) {
      #replace text
      s/\Q$oldname\E/$newname/i;
   }
   #match end of user stanza
   if ( /^end user $oldname/i )  {
         s/\Q$oldname\E/$newname/i;
   }
   print;
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: In the end stanza there are 3 possible format rules as explained in 2.1,2.2,2.3. Will it work for all the 3 cases?

Comment: If it doesn't, extend the pattern slightly - write them as separate rules, and you're good.